# PHP - Converting String to Array that is already formated as an array

Tags: php

For clarification purposes I am using 2 separate files. So I am trying to check if a value exist within my array that is generated in my 2nd file. The first file stores the input below...

```
//mytxtfile.txt previous content stored in a text file using file_put_content and print_r...
Array
(
    [0] => Bill
    [1] => Bob
    [2] => Joe
    [3] => Frank
    [4] => Mark
)
```

My 2nd file I try to call file_get_content but now realize that it stores my input as a string. Is there any way to convert this string back to an array in my new file? I have tried json_decode but it says it is null... Or if this is too much of a hassle I am also willing to change the format on how it is stored in the 1st file that generates the content.

Comment: print_r is not serialisation, instead use, [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) then [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) or [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).. converting it back is not easy.. https://print-r-converter-199219.appspot.com/ https://github.com/lcherone/print_r-converter

Comment: oh okay... so I switched my 1st file to json_encode instead and it works.... thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain the solution in details , but first let me post the code:

```
    <?php //php 7.0.8

        $input = "Array
        (
            [0] => Bill
            [1] => Bob
            [2] => Joe
            [3] => Frank
            [4] => Mark
        )";

        $lines = explode("\n", $input); 
        $values = array();
        for ($i = 2; $i < count($lines) - 1; $i++) {
            $value = explode("=>", $lines[$i])[1];
            $value = trim($value);
            array_push($values, $value);
        }

        print_r($values);
    ?>
```

So the file contains the formatted array as a text , we will split the content of the file into lines , this can be done using `explode()` function , now the `$lines` array contains the text rows of the file.
Now we will loop to extract the values , notice that the loop starts from `$i = 2` , this because we're ignoring the first line (which contains `Array`) and the second line (which contains `(`) , and the loop ends right before the last line , because we're ignoring the last line (which contains `)`).
We initialize an empty array `$values` to store the values of the array , to do this we again need to split each line using `explode()` function , but having in mind that the separator is `=>` , this will return an array similar to ("[0]", " Bill") , since we want the string " Bill" we use the index 1.
Next (this step is optional) , we get rid of the whitespace before the value using the `trim()` function.
Finally , we push the resultant `$value` into the empty array.
When the loop ends you will get the extracted values.
For the sake of reference , here's the documentation of the used functions:
`trim()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php
`explode()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
`array_push()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

    $input = "Array
    (
        [0] => Bill
        [1] => Bob
        [2] => Joe
        [3] => Frank
        [4] => Mark
    )";

    $pattern = '/\[(?<keys>\w+)\]\s=>\s(?<values>\S+)/';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches);
    $values = $matches['values'];
    $keys = $matches['keys'];
    $result = array_combine($keys, $values);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: This limits to indexed arrays, if you change the \d+ to \w+ then it will handle associative arrays too.